# Why isn't renormalization called dark physics?

Tags: renormalization, dark-matter, dark-energy

In QED there is extra energy that has to be gotten rid of to match observations. Kind of the opposite to GR/ND where you have to add extra energy/matter to match observations.
Why isn't renormalization considered as missing dark negative energy or dark dynamics or dark physics etc?

Comment: What does "ND" stand for?

Comment: Newtonian dynamics, I take it that DM  and DE are needed in those equations too to renormalize things.

Comment: What do "DM" and "DE" stand for?

Comment: @user26143: Dark Matter and Dark Energy

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to encourage posters to spell out abbreviations (at least once). Abbreviations may not be obvious to readers with a different background.

Answer (score 6):

Renormalisation is a computational technique. Calculating scattering amplitudes directly gives infinite results, but the process of (i) regularising the theory (ii) calculating using the regulated theory then (iii) taking the regularisation parameter to its physical limit gives the finite result that matches experiment.

By contrast the computations in GR are free of (unphysical) divergences and the observation of dark energy does not indicate a problem in our computational technique. You could argue ([and some do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics)) that it indicates a deficiency in the mathematical model we are using, but the consensus view is that dark energy is something real.

So renormalisation and dark energy are completely different things.

Comment: I still feel that regularsing should be equal to some unseen/dark physical process that stops the universe being filled with virtual particles and gives the Casimir effect the value it has. Isn't there some thought on why 4pi pops up in a few places?

Comment: What about the zero-point energy? I've read in introductory QFT books that whilst fixing your zero point energy after, say, quantizing fermions by subtracting an infinity is of no physical consequence, within GR it would be relevant, as all energy contributes to SEM tensor. Perhaps there is a tenuous connection between renormalization and dark energy then?

Comment: There is an open question why zero point energy apparently doesn't gravitate, and on the same theme why the Higgs field doesn't gravitate. No-one knows the answer.